# What's the difference between "HTTP request" and "Webhook request" in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The function.json files are very similar. Too similar for me to understand the difference.

What sorts of scenarios would I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 10):

You can just consider Webhook to be a more specific version of an HTTP request. The major difference being that WebHooks are generally configured to only respond to POST requests where as HTTP Requests can be used with all REST Verbs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still unclear on why I would choose one over the other. Can you provide an example where Webhook is more appropriate than the standard HTTP request type?

Comment: Webhook is more appropriate if you're implementing a Webhook such as Github or Slack as it will set up more boilerplate for you for interacting with these services. You could still use a regular HTTP triggered function to service a Webhook but you'll have to manually ensure that things are set up properly (accepts only POST for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think webhook differs from simple HTTP request as to how do you want to trigger the function. HTTP request based trigger can be used when an explicit HTTP request is made to trigger the function. While in case of webhook, function will be triggered as soon as it receives some data from webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have LogicAPP which connects to Automation account runbook to process the file.
HTTP Request - will simply send data to runbook and close the connection after receiving 200 or 202 responses. Whereas Webhook Request will not stop after receiving the 200 or 202 response. It will keep on running unless you unsubscribe it using callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between both is the callback URL.
POST request does not have a callback URL but webhook has a callback URL.

Example: I have to update the DB, and I created a post request. In logic App, my post request is completed movement I receive 200 or 202 in response. Where is if I used Webhook, then my step in the logic app is not marked as completed unless the callback URL is triggered.